# How to do java.net.InetSocketAddress optimization

Tags: java, sockets

I found the bottleneck of my program is Class InetSocketAddress.
It used almost 90% of the CPU time.

Comment: Can you show an actual stack trace of which method is causing this high usage?

Comment: Just remove that line of code and you're program will run 90% faster!

Comment: Sorry I couldn't resist.  I try not to troll as much as possible.

Comment: I mean that 90% of the total cpu usage of my program in Jprofile!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably doing either a DNS lookup or a reverse DNS lookup.  As comments say, knowing which method is involved is important.

Comment: Except, DNS lookups are network latency-bound, not CPU-bound.